# How to submit/update/delete data through InfoPath Form to an MS Access Database on Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath-2007

I want submit Data/update/delete through InfoPath Form to an MS Access Database on Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS 2007), If custome code require please give code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would consider setting up a data connection within InfoPath to submit the form data to a SharePoint document library. Then you could can link your Access Database to that same doc lib. No code needed!

Comment: Do i need to write to sever side code for submit data into sql server/MS Acess .

Comment: No custom code is needed for the solution I described. The data would live in SharePoint and Access would just link to it.